# Bash completion of parameters when using sudo

Tags: bash, centos, sudo, autocomplete

I am using CetnOS 6 and want to have autocompletion for parameters while using `sudo`.

I found this question https://superuser.com/questions/804128/bash-hints-does-not-work-after-sudo-or-man and now the following works:

- `yu[tab]` completes to `yum` and with another tab press it suggests the different yum commands
- `yum upg[tab]` autocompletes to `yum upgrade` as desired
- `sudo yu[tab]` autocompletes to `sudo yum` as expected
- `sudo yum upg[tab]` **does not autocomplete** to anything, also no suggestions.

How can I achieve parameter completion even when using sudo?

(I used `yum` just as an example because it is available on all CentOS; the result is the same for other commands.)

---

Some informations about my system:

```
$ uname -a
Linux server 2.6.32-642.6.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 5 00:36:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

$ yum list installed | grep completion
bash-completion.noarch  1:1.3-7.el6        @epel

$ cat .bashrc
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
complete -cf sudo
```

Comment: Bash completion does not have sudo available. Look at /etc/bash_completion.d.

Comment: I don't understand. There is no file called sudo in `/etc/bash_completion.d` - yes. But on my ubuntu/debian systems there is also no such file in there but there parameter completion works. `sudo apt-get di[tab]` completes to `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` as desired

Comment: Ubuntu provides its own bash completion scripts/rules than other distributions. You will need to look at the files the bash-completion package in ubuntu provides, find the one for sudo and go from there. it may not be named as such, but you can use grep to find it.

Comment: but where should I search? I did a grep for sudo on everything in `/etc/bash_completion.d` and found nothing. It must be somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Not the perfect workaround, but you can add `complete -cf sudo` to your `.bashrc` which will autocomplete sudo commands thereon.

However, in doing so, it will not act *exactly* like normal tab completion. for example, if you were to use this, and then `sudo cd [tab]` you will get a lot of possibilities that won't be useful - i.e a file names will show... who wants to cd to a file?

For the most part though, it will complete commands like `sudo yum upd[tab]`